# PHP SOAP fread() dynamic POST size

Tags: php, soap, post, size, fread

Looking to read the file size of the SOAP POST, any best practices?

```
$data = fopen('php://input','rb');
$content = fread($data,5000);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);
```

Would like the 5000 to be dynamic as each SOAP POST size will be different or does this matter?

Using fread() would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm. If you can read it with '`fread`', I see no reason you cannot read EXACT same text with '`file_get_contents()`'. I use this a few times and remembering that I've try both.

As far as the best practice for '`fread`' goes, what you need is the file size which you can get it from getallheaders().

So, if you still prefer using '`fread`' here is the code.

```
$data = fopen('php://input','rb');
$Headers = getallheaders();
$CLength  = $Headers['Content-Length'];
$content = fread($data,$CLength);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);
```

The code above is self explained so there is no need for further explanation. Just a little bit note that if the length is [longer than 8192 bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) the content will be clipped. So you better check the read length to see if it clipped. (You will not need to be worry if you use '`file_get_contents()`' though).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I think this will do it :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following instead:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input')
```

This will get all contents, no matter the length of the data.

Comment: I was using this but I couldn't get it to work with DOMDocument() and load the XML

Comment: That's odd. I haven't used it with DOMDocument, but I've used it with SimpleXMLElement, and it works just fine.

Comment: I also tried SimpleXML with no luck as to what I wanted to do. The code I have works just wanted to know how I could make the size dynamic instead of hard coding it. Thanks for the help

Comment: It may be that your fopen wrappers (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are disabled. I'm not sure that it would affect php:// URLs, but it may.